# Refactor conditional SQL inner join from C# to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, join

I have a repository class which uses a query that is constructed in C# by concatenating strings based on certain conditions.
I want to move this query from C# code to stored procedures. Now a piece of code does an inner join with a huge user table ( I am talking about millions of records) based on a condition.
Here is the snippet.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("  SELECT");
    sb.AppendLine("  I.[Code] AS ItemCode, IP.[PlatformCode]");
    sb.AppendLine("  FROM [product].[ProductPlatform] PP");
    sb.AppendLine("  JOIN [product].[Product] P ON PP.[ProductId] = P.[Id]");
    if (condition)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("    JOIN [user].[UserItem] UI ON I.[ItemCode] = UI.[ItemCode] AND IP.[PlatformCode] = UI.[PlatformCode] AND UI.[UserId] = @UserId");
    }
    if (condition2)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("    JOIN [user].[UserProductItem] UPI ON I.[Code] = UPI.[ProductItemCode] AND UPI.[UserId] = @UserId");
    }
    ...
```

There are other joins but they are not important. Now the two join strings will be totally ignored if the two conditions are false.
Now I want to move the entire SQL code into Stored Proc without compromising performance. I don't want the two joins be executed if the conditions are false, because those two tables are huge.
I created the following stored procedure where I pass the two C# condition variables as parameters to my stored proc, but I think a) it is not the same logic as if the condition is not met the query returns nothing, I guess I need a left join and b) performance is not preserved as before.

```
    JOIN [user].[UserItem] UI ON a.[ItemCode] = UI.[ItemCode] AND PP.[PlatformCode] = UI.[PlatformCode] AND UI.[UserId] = @UserId AND (@onlyConditionMet = 1)


    JOIN [user].[UserProduct] UP ON P.[Code] = UP.[ProductCode] AND UP.[UserId] = @UserId AND (@onlyCondition2Met = 1)
```

Now the question is how can I best move my code to stored proc by preserving performance and not changing the query too much.

**UPDATE**: Based on the solutions suggested by the folks here I ended up using IF blocks. My code is now verbose, but I have preserved performance which is paramount for my query. Now my code looks like this:

```
    IF ( condition1 = true AND condition2 = true AND condition3 = true)
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM someTable
            LEFT JOIN someOtherTable on someCondition
        END
    ELSE IF ( condition1 = true AND condition2 = true AND condition3 = false)
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM someTable
            LEFT JOIN someOtherThanTheOtherTable on someOtherCondition
        END
    ...
    ELSE IF ( condition1 = false AND condition2 = false AND condition3 = false)
        BEGIN
            -- Do something else
        END
```

Comment: check out dynamic sql? http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: In T-SQL exists the IF statement.

Comment: @Steve True. But I don't think I can use the IF statement within my join clause. The IF should be used for the entire select statement. As I explained to Joel in the answers, I have 15 different conditions for the entire select statement. I don't think I can write a different query based on different conditions.

Comment: For the record a 50 million record table is not huge to SQL server.

Comment: Of course I was talking about the IF to separate your logic in different queries. But I don't know if you are more concerned about the performance of your queries or about the amount of code that you need to write (and maintain). If you are interested in performances I think that you should use the IF and avoid at all costs the dynamic sql. Another possible approach (to be tested for their performance) is to create separate VIEWs of your data and query about these views

Comment: @HLGEM I was off a bit. 323 Million, but you are right. It is costly operation though to join on a 323 million records table vs a 5000 records table :)

Comment: @Steve That sounds like a good option to use views, I am not sure about the performance either. I am a bit conservative in trying new approaches when user related tables are involved. We had situations where our database was rendered unusable due to using un-optimized queries for user related tables. Maybe I should write the different IF statements and separate logic as you suggested.

Comment: @Steve Your solution to use IF statements was finally what I chose for different combination of my code. I chose performance over verbosity of code.

Answer (score 2):

Just make :

```
IF @condition = 1
[...  First SELECT WITH first JOIN ... ]
ELSE
[...  Second SELECT WITH second JOIN ... ]
```

Moreover, in terms of performance, using "dynamic queries" with Ado makes SQL Server recompiles the query and process a new execution plan each time. Using a stored procedure or a function will be faster than a dynamic query in Ado, since the query is compiled just once when you add it to your Database.

Moreover bis : If there is only some SELECT statements in your procedure, and each time the same returned values, why not make a Table Function ?

PS : From a performance point of view, it's not sure that a boolean inside the JOIN clause is less efficient that such a IF/THEN case. You should look at the execution plans and make some tests. SQL Server is really smart sometimes.

Comment: Dynamic queries seems like a good enough option. Constructing my query like the one I am using with C# code and executing pieces of it based on a condition parameter. Table Function is not a good solution. We have tried it before. Problem was that it does a huge use of tempdb and lots of contention occur as a consequence of it. So I prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [sq_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), but you may want to write this as a high-level IF block:

```sql
If condition And NOT condition2
Begin

 -- Do query with UserItem join

end
if (NOT condition) And condition2
Begin

 -- Do query with UserProduct join

end
if condition And condition2

 -- Do query with both joins

end
```

Finally, depending on your conditions, you may be able to write them into the JOIN clause by using an OUTER JOIN type:

```
LEFT JOIN [user].[UserItem] UI ON condition AND I.[ItemCode] = UI.[ItemCode] AND IP.[PlatformCode] = UI.[PlatformCode] AND UI.[UserId] = @UserId
```

You mentioned performance as a concern, so I'll add that this last option can still perform quite well if the columns referenced for your condition are constant or match up well with the table indexes.

Comment: There are more than two conditions. I just mentioned those two conditions in my question just for simplicity. There are 15 different joins each based on a certain C# boolean variable. So I don't think I can write a query for all different combination of my conditions.

Comment: You think doing a left join on a table which contains some 50 million records with all the right indexes can perform quite well? I shouldn't be concerned?

Comment: Yes, it _can_ perform well. You should be concerned, because whether it _will_ perform well can take some query tuning, but with a bit of extra work you should be able to get it. Also note how I added the condition to the join. With luck and some cajoling, you should be able to get sql server to work that into the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I ended up using your first recommendation. I deleted unnecessary conditions and ended up with three condition and 8 combinations. DBAs at my company didn't like LEFT JOINING the user tables too much when it was not necessary.